# How do I count the number of times that checkbox is in disabled mode in a gallery?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I need code that reports back to a text label called lblDis where I am getting a count of the number of instances where the checkbox value chkVal's disabled mode is set to disable in the gallery galTick.

I have tried this:

Code in OnVisible of the screen:

ClearCollect(colDisabledCount, Filter(galTick.AllItems, chkVal.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Disabled));
UpdateContext({disabledCount: CountRows(colDisabledCount)});

but that throws an error that .DisplayMode is not available in this context.

Code in lblDis:
"Disabled Count: " & disabledCount

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can count these values this way.

There are two alternative approaches I could recommend:

1. In the checkbox OnChange, increment/decrement a global counter variable.
2. In the checkbox OnChange, update with a new boolean field in your data source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You cannot reach DisplayMode like that. You can only reach Text, Value, Tooltip, and Content Language of checkbox in some formulas. My suggestion is to change Tooltip of checkbox according to DisplayMode.

```
If(Self.DisplayMode=DisplayMode.Disabled,"Disabled","")
```

After that, You can easily count checkboxes DisplayMode's with their tooltips and sum them. You should place below code in your label's Text property.

```
Sum(ForAll(galTick.AllItems,If(ThisRecord.chkVal.Tooltip="Disabled",1,0)),ThisRecord.Value)
```